# Is there any C# analogue of Node.js?

Tags: c#, node.js, asynchronous, mono

Is there any C# analogue of Node.js?
I want a lightweight async http and websocket server.

Required platform: mono.

Answer (score 2):

There are some. I know following:

1. NancyFX - http://nancyfx.org/. There is a good pack of links on [Scott Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast270NancySinatraAndTheExplosionOfNETMicroWebFrameworksWithAndreasH%C3%A5kansson.aspx)
2. ServiceStack -http://www.servicestack.net/ - more complicated, but much more powerful

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good list of your options (along with an async server example).

I use httpserver myself, and it works fine for my requirements.

http://blog.tedd.no/2012/07/28/asyncawait-http-server-in-c

Comment: Good sample, but AFAIK it's not async, it's threaded.